# Ajax implementation of like,comment and post feature

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have added features of comment,like and make status posts in my website.
But the problem is i want to use ajax for improving its dynamic performance.
But i cant implement ajax. i have the snapshot of the front end where ajax is to be added. I have used PHP.
if anyone can help me to add this.... thanks in advance.

[Snapshot of the section to be implemented via ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWV6P.png)

I want to delete and add comments without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: you have to try first, then post your code and if you have any issues, we can help you :)

Comment: The comment you are showing is coming from ajax ?? if that is so then you have to bind your delete ajax call on success of comment ajax call.

Comment: actually all u can see is wat i have implemented in php....and i want to implement ajax so that my pages do not get refreshed after each like and comment